# "Cout" messages do not show on c++ launched console app from Unity

Tags: c++, unity-game-engine, process, system.diagnostics

On my Unity Project I'm launching an external c++ simple console App.

My c++ console App:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp)
{
    // Display each command-line argument. 
    int count;
    std::cout << "\nCommand-line arguments:\n";
    for (count = 0; count < argc; count++)
        std::cout << "  argv[" << count << "]   "
        << argv[count] << "\n";

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the app shows the name of the arguments passed, and if I run manually the application it looks like: 
[image]

**But when I launch the same app from Unity, the console prompt is empty**.
This is how I launch the c++ app from Unity:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Launcher : MonoBehaviour {

    Process process = null;
    private void Start()
    {
        StartProcess();
    }

    void StartProcess()
    {
        try
        {
            process = new Process();
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = Application.dataPath + "/ConsoleTestApplication.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "1 1 1"; //Without passing arguments, it also appears empty
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.Start();
            process.BeginOutputReadLine();

            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Successfully launched app");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Unable to launch app: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

The app is launched, and the console window appears, completly empty, any idea about what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MichaWiedenmann and thanks for the fast comment, as far as I know, If i press "enter" to the open command window, it's the only input that I've to pass to the process, isn't it? Also, where you think I should flush the buffer? before getchar I tried but it doesn't change anything? Thanks!

Comment: You're reading output asynchronously, but you haven't assigned an output received handler.  See the [`BeginOutputReadLine` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Diagnostics_Process_BeginOutputReadLine).  If you want the child process to write output to its own console, set the `RedirectStandardOutput` property to `false`.

Comment: @MilesBudnek that was the answer, thanks! (If you want, you can answer the question (explaining more extensiveley why it is) and I'll mark it for the future users. (but an error shows the message "Unable to launch app: Standard outpt has not been redirected or process has not been started.)

Comment: Two things I want your to do: **1.** Close Unity or the Editor and reopen your Unity app or the Editor with the `-logfile` argument. Now check if you can see the C++ log. **2.** Create a simply console app. Run this C# code and verify if it's working. Now, you can tell if it's Unity's fault or not. Report back the result

Comment: @Programmer where should be the c++ log? I can't see it :(

Comment: Google "Unity log path". Anyways you can use `process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` to try and obtain the log. Note that my first comment said two things. You haven't mentioned the result of #2

Comment: @Programmer Indeed, but I was assuming the #2 question was answered on my post when I say "and if I run manually the application it looks like" as it should. I'll check the ReadLine(), Thanks.

Comment: When i said "Create a simply console app", I meant do it from C#. No Unity involved then use the C# console program to open the C++ program and test....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184518/discussion-between-lotan-and-programmer).